# CRM 2013 Refresh Subgrid

Tags: javascript, crm

I have a javascript that adds a N:N relationship between two CRM entities via a ribbon function. Everything works fine, the relationship gets added. However I'm having problems refreshing the subgrid that contains the added entity records. Before this function used to work in CRM 2011, but not anymore in 2013.

This used to work in CRM 2011 to refresh "MySubGrid" after a record is added.

```
var gridControl = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("MySubGrid");
if (gridControl != null) {
gridControl.refresh();}
```

I tried below as suggested from a blog and it didn't work either:

```
var propertyStatusControl = document.getElementById("Propertiestatus");
        if (propertyStatusControl != null) {
            propertyStatusControl.refresh();}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try as follows,

```
var propertyStatusControl = document.getElementById("Propertiestatus");
if (propertyStatusControl != null) {
propertyStatusControl.**control**.refresh();}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Renjith. Unfortunately  propertyStatusControl.control.refresh(); here does not work..

I think it has something to do with the if statement if (propertyStatusControl != null) because now all of my commands that supposed to follow the condition doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Yes "Propertiestatus" is the name of the subgrid that I'm trying to get refreshed. I've double-checked the properties of the subgrid.